# Return getItemViewType based on database attribute

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, android-recyclerview

I have a heterogeneous recycler-view adapter that displays a different viewholder depending on the type of the feed item.

The only difference between these view types, aside from their layout XML, is a column in the database called notificationType (String), which assigns either the value "typeLike" or "typeComment".

I would like to return the item type here based on the value in that column, because the layout will be different depending on whether the notification is a "like" or a "comment". Should I put a query in my getItemViewType

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    final ParseObject notifications = mNotifications.get(position);

    switch (holder.getItemViewType(notifications)) {
        case LIKE:
            ViewHolder vh1 = (ViewHolder) holder;
            configureViewHolder1(vh1, position);
            break;
        case COMMENT:
            ViewHolder2 vh2 = (ViewHolder2) holder;
            configureViewHolder2(vh2, position);
            break;
        default:
            RecyclerViewSimpleTextViewHolder vh = (RecyclerViewSimpleTextViewHolder) holder;
            configureDefaultViewHolder(vh, position);
            break;
    }
}


@Override
public int getItemViewType(ParseObject notifications) {
    if (notifications.getString("notificationType").equals("typeLike")) {
        return LIKE;
    } else {
        return COMMENT;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the above code does not override from its super class. How should I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `getItemViewType` accepts `int position`, I can create the notification object inside the `getItemViewType` method:

```
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        final ParseObject notifications = mNotifications.get(position);
        if (notifications.getString("notificationType").equals("typeLike")) {
            return LIKE;
        } else {
            return COMMENT;
        }
    }
```

This way I'm not touching the `onBindViewHolder` method. Totally escaped me that I could call my list inside `getItemViewType` independently.

Comment: This is pain mate. You might want to check out [this article](https://medium.com/@dpreussler/writing-better-adapters-1b09758407d2#.hicl5zt13). Cheers.